# How to get SEO meta tag in Rankmath

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

I'm pretty new to WordPress plugin development. I am trying to move from Yoast to Rankmath. I have a question about get seo meta tag in Rankmath.

In Yoast, I can get SEO meta tag (for example title tag) by a function like this:

```
function click_the_meta_title()
{
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true) !='')
    {
      return  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);  
    }
    else {
      return get_the_title();
    }
}
```

How can I get those tags with RankMath?

Comment: A `<title>` tag is not a meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

In RankMath, you can use the following function to get the SEO meta title for a post or page:

```
function get_rank_math_meta_title() {
    return RankMath\Post::get_meta( 'title' );
}
```

This will return the SEO meta title set in the Rank Math SEO plugin for the current post or page. If the SEO meta title is not set, it will return the post or page title by default.

You can also use the following function to get the SEO meta description for a post or page:

```
function get_rank_math_meta_description() {
    return RankMath\Post::get_meta( 'description' );
}
```

This will return the SEO meta description set in the Rank Math SEO plugin for the current post or page. If the SEO meta description is not set, it will return the post or page excerpt by default.

Please note that you will have to make sure the RankMath plugin is activated and setup properly before using those functions.

Comment: Hi Jahidul, thank you for this, I have activated the Rank Math plugin and i'm currently trying to implement your suggestions but I don't have access to the RankMath class. Is it a package that needs to be installed?

Comment: Yes, the RankMath class is part of the Rank Math SEO plugin for WordPress and it needs to be installed and activated on your website before you can use it.
Please note that you should use the functions only in the WordPress context (e.g. on the website that has the plugin installed and activated) otherwise it will not work.